# I can't prepare multiple databases in Django (sqlite3)

Tags: django, django-models

There is a problem which I can't understand how that happens.

## First let me clear what do I want:

- Use a database called **sol_data.sqlite3** for two models: SolModel1, SolModel2 (These models defined in an app called sol_app)
- Use a database called **db.sqlite3** for any other models like always (Django built-in models and other apps)
  It's obvious **db.sqlite3** should not include SolModel1 and 2. and **sol_data.sqlite3** should only include SolModel1 and 2 tables.

But when I migrate, both tables have all django models, and **sol_data.sqlite3** have SolModel1 and 2 addition to them. I'm confused. (I have already read the docs: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/multi-db](https://stackoverflow.com))

## My code

**settings.py**

```
... # other settings
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    },
    "sol_data_db": {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'sol_data_db.sqlite3',
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ["sol_app.dbrouters.SolDataRouter"]
... # other settings
```

**sol_app/dbrouters.py**

```
class SolDataRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == "sol_app":
            return "sol_data_db"
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == "sol_app":
            return "sol_data_db"
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if (obj1._meta.app_label == "sol_app" and obj2._meta.app_label == "sol_app"):
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label == "sol_app":
            return db == "sol_data_db"
        else:
            return None
```

**my terminal**

```
➜ python manage.py makemigrations
➜ python manage.py migrate 
➜ python manage.py migrate --database=sol_data
```

## UPDATE

for SolModel1, db_table = "sol_model_1" (class Meta)

**models.py**

```
    class SolModel1(models.Model):
        name = charfield...
        class Meta:
            db_table = "sol_model_1"

    class SolModel2(models.Model):
        name = charfield...
        solmodel1 = foreignkey to SolModel1
        class Meta:
            db_table = "sol_model_2"
```

Comment: can you give us the models code? Have you set at `SolModel1` `db_table = 'sol_data'` in it's meta class?

Comment: for SolModel1, db_table = "sol_model_1" (And for the other one like this too). models doesn't have anything special. Just SolModel2 has ForeignKey to SolModel1. they are not related to any model from another app or Django apps.